# Генератор имен на php по слогам из массива

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, нужен генератор имен, берущий случайные слоги из массива, интересуют варианты как это можно сделать через implode и вариант с конкатенацией.

Случайные слоги разобрался как выводить, а вот как это объединить - не пойму, в частности не понятно как обратиться к отдельным элементам цикла, что бы их объединить

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

/* Слоги, из которых составляется имя */
$letters = array(
    'ко',   'и',    'дзу',  'ми',
    'са',   'ку',   'ра',   'да',
    'чи',   'а',    'ки',   'ми',
    'на',   'го',   'ха',   'ру'
);

/* В эту переменную запишем получившееся имя */
$name = '';

/* Гененрируем 4 слога */
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {   
    /* Выкидываем случайное число (count - число элементов в массиве) */
    $random = array_rand($letters); 
    $randomText = $letters[$random];

    echo "Выпало число {$random}, слог {$randomText}\n";
    ....
}

echo "------\n";
echo "Советую имя: {$name} - не прогадаешь!\n";
?>
```

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eaf787562087ec18331fc428ac2ad33227338a7a

Comment: как двустрочный вариант без повторов слогов `$tmp = shuffle($letters); echo implode('', array_slice(array_shuffle($tmp),0,4))` Если с повторами, то можно продублировать массив 4 раза

Comment: @СтасКалиновский пример от teran [смотреть](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10d0cbed60c1cf6dd088b02fb00be8bf6187867d)

Answer (score 0):

Вариант с использованием функции `implode()`.

Случайные слоги записываются в массив `$slog`, и, после цикла, склеиваются через функцию `implode()` в строку `name`.

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);

$letters = array(
    'ко',   'и',    'дзу',  'ми',
    'са',   'ку',   'ра',   'да',
    'чи',   'а',    'ки',   'ми',
    'на',   'го',   'ха',   'ру'
);


for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {   
    $random = array_rand($letters); 
    $randomText = $letters[$random];
    $slog[]=$randomText;
    echo "Выпало число $random, слог $randomText<br>";

}

$name=implode("",$slog);
echo "------\n";
echo "Советую имя: $name - не прогадаешь!\n";
?>
```